# Is there a word for being vaguely attracted to something or someone against your own will?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to think of one word but I can't do it without 'reluctantly' attached!

For example, “Despite his bad reputation, she was … by him.”

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should try  to show your own research, as you have outlined with your comment about “reluctantly”. You should also give an example sentence for single word requests, so I have edited to show how the word might occur in a sentence. You should always follow the site guidelines/help or your questions may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite think of any one-word phrases at the moment, but the closest two-word phrase I can conjure up would be "morbidly curious", even though it's more focused on the subject being actively curious instead of that being against their will...

Other words to more emphasize the "against your own will" would perhaps be "gravitate" or "charmed", both taking weight of the attraction away from the subject and instead implying the attraction to be more passive on the subject's end.